# How to filter select options in SQLFORM, web2py?

Tags: web2py

I want to select only authenticated teachers' students on the form. But I could not find how to filter. Can you help?
Best,

```py
db.define_table(
    'student',
    Field('first_name', length=50, requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(), notnull=True, label='Name'),
    Field('last_name', length=50, requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(), notnull=True, label='Last Name'),
    Field('is_active', 'boolean', label=T('Active?')),
    auth.signature,
    format='%(first_name)s %(last_name)s')
db.define_table(
    'student_teacher',
    Field('teacher', 'reference auth_user', 
        default=auth.user_id, 
        represent=lambda x, row: db.auth_user[x].first_name + " " + db.auth_user[x].last_name),
    Field('student', 'reference student', 
        represent=lambda x, row: db.student[x].first_name + " " + db.student[x].last_name
        ),
    auth.signature)
db.define_table(
    'session_header',
    Field('session_date', type="date", label='Session Date'), 
    Field('teacher', 'reference auth_user', notnull=True, readonly=True, default=auth.user_id),
    Field('student', 'reference student', notnull=True),
    auth.signature)
subset = db(db.student_teacher.teacher == request.vars.teacher)
db.student_teacher.student.requires = IS_IN_DB(
    db, db.student.id, '%(first_name)s %(last_name)s', 
    zero=T('Choose one'), 
    _and=IS_NOT_IN_DB(subset, 'student_teacher.student'))

def create():
    form = SQLFORM(session_header)
    if form.process().accepted: 
        response.flash = "Record inserted successfully."
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash = "Please correct the form errors."
    response.view = 'sessions/create.html'
    return dict(form=form)
```

Also I've added student_teacher table.

Comment: How do you know which students in the `student` table belong to a given teacher? What does the `student` table look like?

Comment: added student table...

Comment: In the `session_header` form, you only want to see students who are associated with the teacher that is the currently logged in user, correct? If so, how do you know which students those are? The `student` table does not include a field associating the student to a given teacher, so where does that information come from?

Comment: Yes, true. Also I've added "student_teacher" many-to-many table (forgotten previous post).